# django admin list filter limit elements

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I can see in django admin page filters as using `list_filter = ('founded_date','contact')` is there way to limit what's displayed in date field. e.g. only show 'This month' and 'This year' and block 'Today'... any pointers are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). It's extremely easy to write your own filters for the admin.

Comment: If, on the other hand, the only thing you want is to remove the `Today` filter, then you can also remove it via `jQuery`.

Comment: so I should write my own filter `list_filter = ('custom_founded_date')` and remove default one `list_filter = ('founded_date')`

Comment: Yes. And you could also add other filters inside it like, say `Past Hour` or something.

Comment: ok I thought there will some option to just edit default one

Comment: Nope. There isn't!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most efficient way is to write [your own admin filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). That way you'll have complete control of your filter.

It's extremely easy and once you get used to it you'll love it. It can also be **reused** to other `ModelAdmin` classes.

If, on the other hand, you only want to hide the `Today` option then you can do it via `jQuery`, but I do not recommend it since if someone knows the URL format to apply the filter then he can simply apply it (no matter if the `Today` option is hidden). The first option (writing your own filter) is the way to go.